# grouping data from collections of strings in java

Tags: java, string, collections

I have a collection of strings with some data. for example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("10/10/2012 [user2] some message1");
list.add("10/10/2012 [user1] some message2");
list.add("10/10/2012 [qwwww] some message3");
list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message4");
list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message5");
list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message6");
list.add("12/10/2012 [user3] some message7");
list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message8");
list.add("12/10/2012 [sdsds] some message9");
list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message10");
```

Can you suggest an easy way to count the occurrence of each username, date, or message in Java?

For example by **user** should be

```
user1 = 1
user2 = 4
user3 = 3
sdsds = 1
qwwww = 1
```

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: What assumptions can be made about the strings? Will they always start "dd/MM/yyyy " (10 characters and a space)?

Comment: Max Bilbow, yes

Comment: And the username is always contained between [ ]? followed by a message.

Comment: Max Bilbow, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you can use streams and regexes to sort and group data efficiently however this may not be the most efficient method for smaller data sets.

I did a speed comparison using Streams and Matchers vs. this example using simple String methods:

- Streams & Matcher: 72 milliseconds
- Simple String methods (below): 1 millisecond

The following example uses simple substr and indexOf methods to achieve the same result:

#### Based on the assumptions we discussed

```
public class Example
{

  private static String extractDate(String aS)
  {
    int end = aS.indexOf('[');
    return aS.substring(0, end).trim();

  }

  private static String extractUser(String aS)
  {
    int start = aS.indexOf('[') + 1;
    int end = aS.indexOf(']');

    return aS.substring(start, end);

  }

  private static String extractMessage(String aS)
  {
    int start = aS.indexOf("]") + 1;
    if (aS.length() > start)
    {
      return aS.substring(start).trim();
    } else
    {
      return "";
    }
  }

  static Map<String, Integer> group(List<String> aList, Function<String, String> aExtractor)
  {
    Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

    for (String s : aList)
    {
      String extract = aExtractor.apply(s);
      int count = results.getOrDefault(extract, 0) + 1;
      results.put(extract, count);
    }

    return results;
  }

  static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> aStringIntegerMap)
  {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : aStringIntegerMap.entrySet())
    {
      System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("10/10/2012 [user2] some message1");
    list.add("10/10/2012 [user1] some message2");
    list.add("10/10/2012 [qwwww] some message3");
    list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message4");
    list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message5");
    list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message6");
    list.add("12/10/2012 [user3] some message7");
    list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message8");
    list.add("12/10/2012 [sdsds] some message9");
    list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message10");

    //Note: use of lamdas here can impact performance.
    printMap(group(list, Example::extractUser)); 

    printMap(group(list, Example::extractDate));

    printMap(group(list, Example::extractMessage));

  }
}
```

#### Output

```
user1: 1
user2: 4
qwwww: 1
sdsds: 1
user3: 3
11/10/2012: 2
12/10/2012: 5
10/10/2012: 3
some message9: 1
some message8: 1
some message10: 1
some message7: 1
some message6: 1
some message5: 1
some message4: 1
some message3: 1
some message2: 1
some message1: 1
```

### Speed Comparison

Removing lambdas made the simple test even quicker:

```
public class SpeedComparison
{
  private static String extractUser(String aS)
  {
    int start = aS.indexOf('[') + 1;
    int end = aS.indexOf(']');

    return aS.substring(start, end);
  }


  static Map<String, Integer> group(List<String> aList)
  {
    Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

    for (String s : aList)
    {
      String extract = extractUser(s);
      int count = results.getOrDefault(extract, 0) + 1;
      results.put(extract, count);
    }

    return results;
  }

  final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]");
  static Optional<String> parseValue(String raw) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(raw);
    if (m.find()) {
      return Optional.of(m.group(1));
    } else {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i = 0; i< 100000 ; ++i)
     {
       list.add("10/10/2012 [user2] some message1");
       list.add("10/10/2012 [user1] some message2");
       list.add("10/10/2012 [qwwww] some message3");
       list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message4");
       list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message5");
       list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message6");
       list.add("12/10/2012 [user3] some message7");
       list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message8");
       list.add("12/10/2012 [sdsds] some message9");
       list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message10");
     }


    //Test basic
    final long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    group(list);
    final long dur1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - start1;

    //Test streams
    final long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    list.stream().map(s -> parseValue(s).orElse("missing")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()
    ));
    final long dur2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - start2;

    System.out.println("Speed Comparison");
    //prints ~100, ~1000 milliseconds (10x slower with streams)
    System.out.printf("Test 1: %s%nTest 2: %s",dur1,dur2);
  }
}
```

It is possible that Streams would perform better on significantly larger lists (stream().parallel() may take advantage of multi-threading) but parallelism is not always guaranteed.

#### Size Matters

On my machine, I found that using parallel streams began to catch up when the list size got above 10,000,000 or so.

#### Conclusion

Steams can be very powerful but you should always consider whether they are the best solution for the problem at hand. If in doubt, run some comparison tests.

Answer (score 3):

1. First, let's simplify your code. I'd recommend making a `User` object
   or some sort and make it have `name`, `date` and `message` properties then your list will become `List<User>`.
2. As for grouping the `User` object by some given property, you can utilise the Streams API, in particular, you're interested in the `groupingBy` method.

you can find lots of examples of how to group elements by a given property within the site and here:

- **[Java 8 – Stream Collectors groupingBy examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/)**
- **[Guide to Java 8 groupingBy Collector](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)**

---

Once you've completed *step 1* above, this is a quick example of how to group by the `name` property and it's just as easily extensible to group by another property:

```
Map<String, Long> resultSet = userList.stream().collect(
                      Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(resultSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following outputs: `{user1=1, qwwww=1, user2=4, sdsds=1, user3=3}`

```
public class Main {
    final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]");

    public static Optional<String> parseValue(String raw) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(raw);
        if (m.find()) {
            return Optional.of(m.group(1));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("10/10/2012 [user2] some message1");
        list.add("10/10/2012 [user1] some message2");
        list.add("10/10/2012 [qwwww] some message3");
        list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message4");
        list.add("11/10/2012 [user3] some message5");
        list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message6");
        list.add("12/10/2012 [user3] some message7");
        list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message8");
        list.add("12/10/2012 [sdsds] some message9");
        list.add("12/10/2012 [user2] some message10");

        Map<String, Long> counts = list.stream().map(s -> parseValue(s).orElse("missing")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()
        ));
        System.out.println(counts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a third-party library, you can use the `countBy` method from [Eclipse Collections 9.0](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) which returns a `Bag`.

```
@Test
public void countingSubstrings()
{
    MutableList<String> list = Lists.mutable.with(
            "10/10/2012 [user2] some message1",
            "10/10/2012 [user1] some message2",
            "10/10/2012 [qwwww] some message3",
            "11/10/2012 [user3] some message4",
            "11/10/2012 [user3] some message5",
            "12/10/2012 [user2] some message6",
            "12/10/2012 [user3] some message7",
            "12/10/2012 [user2] some message8",
            "12/10/2012 [sdsds] some message9",
            "12/10/2012 [user2] some message10");

    Bag<String> countsByUser =
            list.countBy(this::findUser);
    Bag<String> countsByMessage =
            list.countBy(this::findMessage);
    Bag<String> countsByDate =
            list.countBy(this::findDate);
}

private String findUser(String string)
{
    return string.substring(string.indexOf('[') + 1, string.indexOf(']'));
}

private String findMessage(String string)
{
    return string.substring(string.indexOf(']') + 2, string.length());
}

private String findDate(String string)
{
    return string.substring(0, string.indexOf('[') - 1);
}
```

A `Bag` has a method `occurrencesOf` which will give you the number of occurrences of a specific item.  The implementation of `HashBag` in Eclipse Collections uses an `ObjectIntHashMap` as its internal data structure, which means you will not be boxing `int` values as `Integer` objects for the counts.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.